# Does a boost converter affect the life span of the source battery?

Tags: battery-charging, boost

Will using a 3 to 5V booster [IC](http://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-DC-Boost-Converter-Step-Up-Module-1-5V-to-5V-500mA-Power-Module-New-S3-/381340232628?hash=item58c9a62bb4:g:pvwAAOSwHnFVsgHS) affect the power capacity of the battery I use in my circuit? as in, will it consume more power?

Comment: Not really - it is a power drained that matters. While the IC itself does consume some power to work, it can be rather omitted because it is pretty small.

Comment: Does the immediate presence of a thirsty person affect the ability of a jug to hold a certain capacity of water?

Comment: Despite what @Andyaka implies, the booster DOES affect **EFFECTIVE** power capacity (or more properly - energy capacity). A 3v to 5V converter is not 100% efficient so you get less energy out than ypou put in. If you were able to accept the battery energy at any voltage across the range supplied by the battery as it discharges then you would get more usable energy than by using a converter. HOWEVER, many circuits cannot efficintly use the battery energy "as supplied" as battery voltage falls and the converter makes it possible for them to do so. SO the converter makes it possible ...

Comment: ... to get more energy from the battery than would otherwise be possible if connected directly BUT this is less than the energy that is input to the converter due to inefficiencies in the converter.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon "capacity" is a measure of volume or, put in techy terms, the maximum charge capacity for a battery so, I must insist that capacity is unaffected by anything connected and my analogy is correct. The amount by which stored energy might diminish is of course affected by load.

Comment: @Andyaka I know you know all this. I still think it's worth saying for completeness. It may not be :-). | I have met the term heretofore :-). The question COULD be understood pedantically from the perspective that you use BUT in most cases and in this case the capacity of a battery as seen by the user is the delivered energy or mAh or Watthours (which I know you know are not all directly equivalent, but that's what people use. I interpret the question as EFFECTIVELY asking if using a converter reduces the energy available to the user and the answer is either ....

Comment: .... YES if you look at total energy delivered by battery versus what the user gets and/but in many cases  NO - just the opposite, as eg a device that needs say 6V can use a nominally 9V Alkaline battery all the way from about 9.9V when new to about 5.4 V when totally exhausted at reasonable conversion efficiency throughout. SO I think the user is not well served by answers which focus on the battery and not the system overall and/or do not spell out what they are doing so a newish comer understands it. Whatever :-) :-) :-) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not directly, the battery capacity is a property of the battery.
The boost converter is just a device that changes the voltage.

What you have to consider is POWER ! Unfortunately battery capacity is often mentioned in Amp-hour, for example 1 Ah means that the battery can deliver 1 Ampere for 1 hour. But it depends on the battery VOLTAGE how much energy that represents ! Obviously a 1 V, 1 Ah battery contains less energy than a 10 V 1 Ah battery. The first is 1 Watt-hour (1 Wh), the second 10 Wh, or 10 times as much energy.

But back to your question, note that a boost converter boosts the voltage. Suppose the output of the boost converter provides 5 V and you load it with 0.1 A, so that is:

5 V x 0.1 A = 0.5 W

Now let's assume your battery is 4 V Will it be loaded also by 0.1 A ?

4 V x 0.1 A = 0.4 W

which is less than 0.5 W, so no this is not correct !

What happens is that the power that goes into the boost converter is about the same as that which comes out (for simplicity I assume the boost converter is 100 % efficient, in practice 90% efficiency is achievable) so there is also 0.5 W going into the boost converter. So your battery is also loaded by 0.5 W so how much current is that ? 0.5 W / 4 V = 0.125 A.
Aha ! That current is higher than the current at the output of the boost converter !

So compare the situation that you draw 0.1 A at 4 V from the battery or use a boost converter and draw 0.1 A at 5 V via a boost converter.
Both cases 0.1 A BUT more power is consumed in the 5 V case.

So that decreases the battery life since you discharge it more quickly !

Battery capacity (how much energy you can extract) also depends on how you load the battery, if you do not load the battery very much you can extract more energy out of it than when you discharge it as quickly as is safe. But this is probably not the effect you were asking about.

Comment: Hello. Could you please check into the following link and help me in solving my question.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/536727/how-to-avoid-battery-draining-when-using-rechargeable-battery-circuit-and-boost

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what do you mean.

Input and output power of the booster are roughly equal, or rather dependent (with subtraction of some loss to heat in the coil and switch element).

However as the power is the product of voltage and current, you will consume more power unless your current consumption becomes less after the raising the voltage.

E.g. if you attach the same resistor-like load to the 3V source and to 5V source, the power consumption will be almost as twice higher with the higher voltage.

So much depends on what load you use with this booster, i.e. on your circuit properties.